# Decoding JSON command line arguments fails after build but succeeds during debug

Tags: c#, json, json.net, command-line-arguments

I am building a C# application that handles a custom protocol used in my web application.

The links are like:

```
<a href="zebra-wp://%7B%22barcode%22%3A63%2C%22name%22%3A%22Food%20Fun%20-%20Magnetic%20Multicultural%20set%22%7D">Print</a>
```

These are handled using a handler in the windows registry (URL:zebra-wp Protocol):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\[My App Name]\[My App].exe" "%1"
```

I am running the following code in my app:

```
class LabelData
    {
        public string name;
        public string barcode;
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].StartsWith("zebra-wp://"))
            {

                // retrieve data from argument
                string argData = args[0].Remove(0, 11);

                string decodedJson = "";
                try
                {
                    // Undo URL Encoding
                    decodedJson = WebUtility.UrlDecode(argData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = "Couldn't print label, failed to decode data.";
                    msg += "\nData: " + argData;
                    msg += "Error: " + ex.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                // Unpack JSON string
                LabelData decodedData = new LabelData();
                try
                {
                    decodedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LabelData>(decodedJson);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = "Couldn't print label, failed to unpack data.";
                    msg += "\nData: " + decodedJson;
                    msg += "Error: " + ex.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(msg);
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                // Do things with object
```

When I debug the application I enter the link URL into the "Command line arguments" start up option.
The program works as expected and the JSON data is successfully decoded.

When I build and install, the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` function gives me the following error:

```
Data: {"barcode":"000063","name":"Food Fun - Magnetic Multicultural set"}
Error: Unexpected end while parsing comment. Path '', line 1, position 68.
```

Is something different about how VS launches an app with command line arguments in debug?
Is there a way to debug the application with the same command line arguments as when I click the URL?

Comment: you can provide the args via project-properties-->debug-->Command line arguments

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, I am doing this, it works when I provide them there, but not when running after install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue, apparently when passing URI's to custom protocol handlers, Windows adds a trailing forward slash to the URI, checking for this in the code and removing it solves the problem.